# High-dimensional integrals with computationally tractable closed-form solutions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, markov-chain-montecarlo, integral

What are some high-dimensional integrals with multimodal integrand and correlated variables, that also have computationally tractable closed-form solutions?

The goal of the above constraints is to prevent the construction of "trivial" integrals by using a series of independent densities. With the goal in mind, please leave a comment if there are loop holes in these constraints.

Here are two examples of what would not fit the bill:

1. Ising model - it is high-dimensional with a closed-form solution to its partition function, but the actual summation is computationally intractable.
2. Sequence of scaled independent univariate Gaussian distributions, resulting in a single mode.

I don't have a threshold for what is defined as high-dimensional, but the motivation is to look for a series of integrals to benchmark Markov chain Monte Carlo methods on.

Comment: Should the integrand (the entire function inside the integral) or the density (only part of the integrand) be multimodal? In the first case, $\mathbb E[\sum_{i=1}^p X_i^2]$ when $X\sim\mathcal N_p(0,\Sigma)$ fits the call.

Comment: I think it would make more sense only the density is multimodal. My rationale is that sampling from the distribution is the tricky part that one would want to test in MCMC.